# "Hibernar" un proceso

Tags: vb.net, .net, hilos

Quiero ser capaz de **hibernar** un proceso, hacer que esté inactivo, que no se ejecute, pero que al quitarle ese estado vuelva a donde estaba justo antes de hibernarlo.

He buscado en internet métodos para hacer esto, pero no he encontrado nada. He probado con la función `SuspendThread`, pero no es lo que quiero.

¿Se puede hacer lo que quiero? ¿Cómo sería en *VB.Net*?

La función de `SuspendThread` que probé lo que hace es bloquear el proceso, pero este sigue ocupando memoria.

Código:

```
Public Enum ThreadAccess As Integer
    TERMINATE = (&H1)
    SUSPEND_RESUME = (&H2)
    GET_CONTEXT = (&H8)
    SET_CONTEXT = (&H10)
    SET_INFORMATION = (&H20)
    QUERY_INFORMATION = (&H40)
    SET_THREAD_TOKEN = (&H80)
    IMPERSONATE = (&H100)
    DIRECT_IMPERSONATION = (&H200)
End Enum

Private Declare Function OpenThread Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal dwDesiredAccess As ThreadAccess, ByVal bInheritHandle As Boolean, ByVal dwThreadId As UInteger) As IntPtr
Private Declare Function SuspendThread Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal hThread As IntPtr) As UInteger
Private Declare Function ResumeThread Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal hThread As IntPtr) As UInteger
Private Declare Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal hHandle As IntPtr) As Boolean
Public Sub SuspendProcess(ByVal process As System.Diagnostics.Process)
    For Each t As ProcessThread In process.Threads
        Dim th As IntPtr`

        th = OpenThread(ThreadAccess.SUSPEND_RESUME, False, t.Id)
        If th <> IntPtr.Zero Then
            SuspendThread(th)
            CloseHandle(th)
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Public Sub ResumeProcess(ByVal process As System.Diagnostics.Process)
    For Each t As ProcessThread In process.Threads
        Dim th As IntPtr

        th = OpenThread(ThreadAccess.SUSPEND_RESUME, False, t.Id)
        If th <> IntPtr.Zero Then
            ResumeThread(th)
            CloseHandle(th)
        End If
    Next
End Sub`
```

¿Es posible hacerlo llamando a una *API* o lo que sea que un proceso **no ocupe ningún recurso**, pero sin embargo al llamar a otra *API*, el proceso vuelva a estar en el estado en el que estaba justo antes de llamar a la primera *API*.

Comment: No está 100% claro lo que quieres. Ayudaría si agregas detalles en cuanto al problema preciso que estás tratando de resolver por medio de este "hibernar". Y también explicar en qué `SuspendThread` no cumple con lo que necesitas.

Comment: Lo que dice sstan + deberías añadir el código que has intentado (con SuspendThread u otro método), para ver si falla por algún motivo.

Comment: Lo que quiero es que se pueda hacer que un proceso no ocupe recursos, como cerrarlo, pero guardar su estado para luego llamar a otra funcion y que recupere ese estado.

Comment: Tal como un pc. Le das a hibernar y es como si estuviera apagado, no consume bateria ni corriente, pero lo enciendes y esta tal cual estaba cuando lo apagaste.

Comment: creo que tendrías que hacer un dump de la memoria del programa con algún programa de debug. Quizá es posible, pero no conozco ninguna aplicación que lo haga. De todas formas cualquier cosa que cambie, por ejempló un fichero cambió mientras el proceso no funcionaba, hará que esa aplicacion tenga un error critico. :P

Comment: Sólo se me ocurre una aplicación que corra en segundo plano, o un servicio, para abrir el proceso cuando lo necesites. El estado lo puedes almacenar en algún tipo de fichero y programar que lea de ahí el estado. No se si esto esta cercano a lo que intentas resolver, como dijeron arriba, sin mucho más datos es dificil ayudar.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes evaluar quizá el aplicar `Windows Workflow Foundation` para esto. Lo que a priori indicas es una `State Machine` o máquina de estados. `WF` usa `SQL Server` como persistencia para almacenar su estado en suspensión. Puedes ver más información en [Programación de Windows Workflow Foundation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dd489462(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Gracias. Lo probaré cuando tenga un hueco.